# Получение id добавляемой записи node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, клиент-сервер, чат, insert

**Задача:** Получить id добавляемой записи как в php, через mysql_insert_id() и вернуть обратно в клиент.

---

**Клиент:**

```
// В начале переменные с данными о пользователе
var ... ;

//Создание блока с сообщением и показ на странице
function msg(avatar, nick, text, my){

// В m нужно добавить получаемый id сообщения
var m = ... ;
   messages
   .append(m)
}

//Получение ответа и отправка данных в функцию
socket.on(dialog, function (data) {
   msg(
      data.avatar, 
      data.name,
      data.text, 
      data.my,
      data.id
   );
});

//Отправка на сервер
socket.emit("chat", {
   id:     dialog,
   my:     my_id
   text:   text, 
   name:   name, 
   avatar: avatar, 
});
```

**Сервер:**

```
client.on('chat', function (chat) {
    try {
        //Получаемые данные пользователя
        var post  = {
            dialog: chat.id, 
            text:   chat.text, 
            users:  chat.my, 
            status: 1, 
            date: new Date()
        };

        //Отправка сообщения в базу данных
        var query = connection.query(
            'INSERT INTO chat SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
            console.log('Добавлено сообщение');
        });

        //Отправка сообщения обратно на страницу 
        client.emit(chat.id, chat);

        //Здесь нужно отправить id сообщения
        client.broadcast.emit(chat.id, chat);

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        client.disconnect();
        connection.end();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в таблице `chat` имеется уникальный `id` с `AUTO_INCREMENT`, то после добавления, вам должен быть доступен `insertId`.

```
//Отправка сообщения в базу данных
var query = connection.query(
    'INSERT INTO chat SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
    console.log('Добавлено сообщение с id = ' + result.insertId);
});
```

[Документация](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row).

Comment: А не подскажите ли, как потом этот id прикрепить к отправляемым данным пользователя обратно? То есть получается chat массив добавить еще одну запись с именем id_chat = result.insertId...

Comment: Я имею ввиду именно как эту переменную потом закинуть в chat массив?

Comment: @АльбертУшаков как вариант, `emit` и `broadcast` перенести в колбэк `connection.query` для синхронности. После того, как пройдет запрос в бд - `chat.id = result.insertId`, ваш `emit` и `broadcast`.

Comment: Ааа вот как. Спасибо.

Comment: Хмм делаю так ...  var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO chat_m13 SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
console.log('Добавлено сообщение');
  chat.id_chat = result.insertId;
  client.emit(chat.id, chat);
  client.broadcast.emit(chat.id, chat);
}); ... не работает.